# Is it worth it to own precious metal ETFs inside a retirement account?

Tags: united-states, etf, capital-gains-tax, retirement-plan, precious-metals

Is it worth it to buy precious metal (e.g. gold and silver) ETFs inside a retirement account (e.g. IRA, Roth IRA and 401(k)) to avoid the hassle of accounting for taxes on these trusts?

Accurately accounting for taxes on precious metal (e.g. gold and silver) ETFs is laborious. The reason is that ETFs (e.g. GLD) collect expenses from the investor by selling fractional shares on a month-by-month basis -- taxable transactions. To make things more complicated, (1) each of these sales includes shares from different tax lots (different cost basis), and (2) some sales incur short-term capital gains tax and some incur long-term capital gains tax.

Here is an excerpt from the GLD prospectus on the trust's tax treatment (another ETF has an excerpt with similar language):

> The Sponsor has received a private letter ruling from the IRS
> concluding that a purchase of Shares by an IRA, or by a
> participant-directed account under a Code Section 401(a) plan (a “plan
> account”), will not be treated as the acquisition of a collectible by
> the IRA or plan, and will not result in a taxable distribution to the
> IRA owner or plan participant under Code Section 408(m). However, if
> Shares are distributed by the trustee or custodian of an IRA or plan
> account to the IRA owner or participant, or if a redemption of any
> Shares held by an IRA or plan account results in the distribution of
> gold to the IRA or account (or such redemption is treated as
> distributed under Section 408), other than Non-Collectible Gold Coins
> or Non-Collectible Gold Bullion, such distribution would be taxable to
> the distributee in the year of distribution to the extent provided
> under the applicable provisions of Code Sections 408(d), 408(m) or
> 402. See also “ERISA and Related Considerations.”

Comment: #1 Is your goal to own precious metals in your retirement account? #2  What's the cost to you of directly owning PMs in your retirement account?  That will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/how-you-can-use-your-ira-to-invest-in-gold-and-other-precious-metals-and-the-federal-tax-implications-11606949164) says that a gold ETF is fine in an IRA.

> Thankfully, the IRS had said that IRAs can buy shares in precious
> metal ETFs that are classified as grantor investment trusts without
> any such problems. Specifically, in Private Letter Ruling (PLR)
> 200732026, the IRS ruled that IRAs could buy shares in a gold ETF.
> This was apparently the SPDR Gold Trust GLD, which is the most
> popular gold ETF. Similarly, in PLR 200732027, the IRS ruled that IRAs
> could buy shares in a silver ETF. This was apparently the iShares
> Silver Trust SLV, which is the most popular silver ETF.