# Do you pay taxes on "phantom" transactions related to precious metal ETFs held inside a retirement account?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, etf, retirement-plan, precious-metals

- Precious metal ETFs (e.g. GLD) collect expenses from you by selling fractional shares on a month-by-month basis
- You have to pay taxes on these sales
- You have to account for fractional shares sold from different tax lots with different cost basis
- You also have to account for short-term gains and long-term gains from different lots
- This is *extremely tedious*
- One possible way to avoid all of this is owning these ETFs inside a retirement account

**BOTTOM LINE: Do you have to pay taxes on such sales when you're holding precious metal ETFs inside a retirement account? (e.g. IRA, Roth IRA, 401(k))**

Here is an excerpt from the GLD prospectus on the trust's tax treatment (another ETF has an excerpt with similar language):

> The Sponsor has received a private letter ruling from the IRS
> concluding that a purchase of Shares by an IRA, or by a
> participant-directed account under a Code Section 401(a) plan (a “plan
> account”), will not be treated as the acquisition of a collectible by
> the IRA or plan, and will not result in a taxable distribution to the
> IRA owner or plan participant under Code Section 408(m). However, if
> Shares are distributed by the trustee or custodian of an IRA or plan
> account to the IRA owner or participant, or if a redemption of any
> Shares held by an IRA or plan account results in the distribution of
> gold to the IRA or account (or such redemption is treated as
> distributed under Section 408), other than Non-Collectible Gold Coins
> or Non-Collectible Gold Bullion, such distribution would be taxable to
> the distributee in the year of distribution to the extent provided
> under the applicable provisions of Code Sections 408(d), 408(m) or
> 402. See also “ERISA and Related Considerations.”

Comment: How is this different from your other question?? [Is it worth it to own precious metal ETFs inside a retirement account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/142291/is-it-worth-it-to-own-precious-metal-etfs-inside-a-retirement-account)

Comment: @Manziel I have flagged that question and closed it instead of deleting it. I realized from reading the comments it was not clear.

Comment: Here is that GLD tax guidance for the 2020 year: https://www.spdrgoldshares.com/media/GLD/file/SPDR-Gold-Trust-Tax-Information-2020.pdf . So wait for the 2021 tax guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The question, the entire set-up, assumes facts that are not true.

The money raised to pay expenses comes from the fact that GLD adjusts the gold it represents by that cost over time. From the sponsor:

> The ordinary operating expenses of the Trust accrue daily and are
> reflected in the NAV of the Trust. The Trustee sells gold held by the
> Trust on an as-needed basis to pay the Trust's expenses. As a result,
> the amount of gold represented by each share will be reduced over
> time, from an initial 1/10th of one ounce of gold. Because the
> expenses of the Trust will be offset by the sale of Trust gold, the
> amount of gold backing each share (Ounces Per Share) will decrease
> gradually.
>
> Each share will initially represent 1/10th of one ounce of gold, but
> this will decline over time. This reduction in ounces per share will
> be reflected in the NAV of the Trust.

At this moment, GLD closed at $169.21, vs gold price, $1808.98. GLD started life as 1/10 oz of gold, but decaying at .4%/yr, they are closer to .094.
Owners of GLD do not see transactions to pay expenses. In fact, this is no different from mutual funds or any other ETF. My S&P ETF pays its expenses from dividends. If an ETF or fund has no dividends, the manager will raise cash via normal transactions, which may or may not result in cap gain distributions at year end. That's a different matter.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and thank you for correcting me: **The sales do not correspond to fractional shares, but rather to small amounts of gold per share**. Nevertheless, this technicality is besides the point of my question. The question is: If you hold a precious metal ETF inside a retirement account, do you have to pay income taxes on these sales?

Comment: The answer is still no. All permitted transactions within a tax-deferred account are not taxable. This is one of the many advantages of an IRA. No worrying about tracking transactions within the account.